# How to get the app version into a bean?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven spring application and want to get the application version into the spring `context.xml` file.

My `pom.xml` file is setup to build war files with the implementation version in the **MANIFEST file**.

I can get the implementation version at runtime like so:

```
String appVersion = MyApp.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

But I need it when creating a bean in the `applicationContext.xml` file.

```
<bean id="myApp" class="MyApp">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="Version" value="version_from_manifest"/>
</bean>
```

I thought of using factory bean and method but can't figure out how to call

```
SomeClassInMyPackage.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Answer (score 0):

In you application.properties add a placeholder application.version.number that will be passed in from Maven.

```
version.number=@application.version.number@
```

Added the placeholder as new property in you pom.xml

```
<application.version.number>${version}</application.version.number>
```

Inject the new config into the Spring bean you need

```
@Value("${version.number}")
private String versionNumber;
```

https://serradev.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/app-version-number-in-java-code-with-maven-and-spring-boot/

Comment: I can't edit the code for the App class so I can't add the @Value for injection. It has a constructor that takes the String value for the version.